# onChange not working at selectedIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I have a CMS and i tried to customize it with jQuery and CSS3 but i got a problem with the language select (drop-down list). 
I customized the `<select>` following this tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2011/02/converting-jquery-code-plugin/

Everything works fine but the **onChange** of the select doesn't work. So when I try to change language from the drop-down list (select) this change only the name in the select but doesn't change language of the site.

This is my select:

```
<select name="lang" class="language" onChange="location.href=\''.$filename.'?lang=\' + this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value +  \''.$trackpage.'\'">
```

I think that the issue is caused by jquery.tzSelect.js (please see the tutorial) because in this plugin there is a `selectedIndex` (this in conflict with the selectedIndex of the select):

```
if(i==select.attr('selectedIndex')){
                    selectBox.html(option.text());
                }
```

I tried to remove this line code from the plugin but doesn't work.
Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: if (i==select[0].options.selectedIndex) {...}

Comment: Thank you @salexch but doesn't work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
this.value
```

instead of

```
this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: Thank you ndlinh!
I tried with `this.value` and `this.value[this.options.selectedIndex].value` but doesn't work

Comment: I has just checked your code above. I think you have wrong string concatenation. Please check \'

Comment: There is no string concatenation error! I have checked the code at phpcodechecker.com and I didn't get any error. I tried with removing `\'` but doesn't work. This is the output (html): `onchange="location.href=index.php?lang= + this.value +  "` and without removing the `\'`: `onchange="location.href='index.php?lang=' + this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value +  ''"` Thank you so much!

Comment: Please try this code:


    <select name="lang" class="language" onChange="window.location='index.php?lang=' + this.value">
       <option value="en_US">English (United State)</option>
       <option value="ja_JP">Japanese</option>
    </select>